# How to get rid of the MeasuresDropControl from a XamPivotGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics

I trying to get rid of the MeasuresDropControl from my XamPivotGrid. It is shown below in the link, having been outlined in red

[image: MeasuresDropControl]

I am trying to position the ColumnsDropControl over the RowsDropControl  (see comment)

In my xamPivotGrid_Loaded, I try to get rid of it using the following:

```
    void xamPivotGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xamPivotGrid.FiltersDropControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        xamPivotGrid.MeasuresDropControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

However, I get the following result:

[image: MeasuresDropControl collapsed view]

How can I get it so that the ColumnDropControl can fill up the space left by the MeasuresDropControl? I have already tried including a style that sets the ColumnDropControl's horizontal allignment to Stretch, but I've gotten the same result.

**Desired Result:**

[image]

Comment: Here is my desired result: [link](http://imgur.com/a/Btubu)